# How to control Bundle null or not?

Tags: android, android-intent

i have 3 Activity in my application and i'm reaching a activity either with a bundle and without bundle and i'm trying to check the bundle null or not. If it's null, open activity, if it's not null write the value to edittext.

here is my code.

```
Bundle veriAl = getIntent().getExtras();

EditText who_detail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.who_detail);
String gelen_deger = veriAl.getString("reply_user").toString();

if(gelen_deger.equals(""))
{
   who_detail.setText(veriAl.getString("reply_user"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
if(veriAl != null){
String gelen_deger = veriAl.getString("reply_user").toString();
}else{
//you got null from bundle
//open other activity here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got the value from another activity with bundle but when i try to open myactivity without bundle it's not working.

Comment: what are you doing to open your activity ??

Comment: i didn't downvote, i can neither downvote or upvote, because my reputation is 11.

Comment: m nt asking to u .. i know u didn't downvoted bt someoneelse downvoted..m asking those ppl ...

Comment: i have 3 activities, the first one is MainActivity, second one is SendMessage and the third one is MyInbox. There is a list of messages in MyInbox activity and i click on item to reply user and opening the SendMessage activity with bundle, and the other job is that i click the menu item SendMessage from MainActivity to open a empty SendMessage activity without a bundle. Finally, when i open SendMessage activity with bundle there is no problem but, when i open the activity without bundle, i'm getting error.

Comment: this is so complicated try to explain more in the question

Comment: Thanks a lot, this post useful to me, the error was about my mistake :) i used just 

pathfinder = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SendMessage.class);
startActivity(pathfinder);
break;   and checked the bundle if it's null or not so it worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
String gelen_deger="";
if(veriAl != null && veriAl.containsKey("reply_user")) gelen_deger = veriAl.getString("reply_user").toString();
```

Comment: thanks you too but i'm still getting error, i wrote my main problem above

i have 3 activities, the first one is MainActivity, second one is SendMessage and the third one is MyInbox. There is a list of messages in MyInbox activity and i click on item to reply user and opening the SendMessage activity with bundle, and the other job is that i click the menu item SendMessage from MainActivity to open a empty SendMessage activity without a bundle. Finally, when i open SendMessage activity with bundle there is no problem but, when i open the activity without bundle, i'm getting error.

Comment: Please show the error you get in LogCat and the 3 Activities (mainly the Intent and onCreate parts).

Comment: The error was about my mistake :) i used just 

pathfinder = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SendMessage.class);
startActivity(pathfinder);
break;   and checked the bundle if it's null or not so it worked, thanks a lot.